# How to fix "Error in UseMethod("select") : no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "function""?

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, ggplotly

I am trying to create an *interactive map in R* with the **covid-19 prison data in the U.S.** dataset given (after tidying), trying to plot a map of different variables (ex. staff cases, prisoner cases, prisoner deaths) and having a slider for the different months out of 15 months.

A sample of my dataset for one of the 50 states is seen here:
[Sample set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpX4D.png)

Below is my code so far, and I am quite stuck on everything from asterisk divider and below. I keep getting an error message saying that `Error in UseMethod("select") :    no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "function"` when I try to use select within the created function STATE, though I don't know if that function is correct at all with what I am trying to do.

Any help would mean the world.

```
if (!require(Lahman)) install.packages('Lahman')
if (!require(plotly)) install.packages('plotly')
if (!require(shiny)) install.packages('shiny')
if (!require(tidyverse)) install.packages('tidyverse')
library(albersusa)
library(shiny)
library(Lahman)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

my_map_theme <- function(){
  theme(panel.background=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank())
}

# Load Dataset from CSV, Dataset saved and tidied from Github
cpc <- read_csv("cpc.csv")
us_states <- usa_sf("laea")
cpc_tidy <- cpc %>%
  select(name,  
         staff_tests,
         total_staff_cases,
         total_staff_deaths,
         prisoner_tests,
         total_prisoner_cases,
         total_prisoner_deaths,
         as_of_date,
         year,
         Month) %>%
  arrange(name)

cpc_tidy_f <- cpc_tidy %>%
  group_by(name, year, Month) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), last))

cpc_sel <- cpc_tidy_f
cpc_sel$merge <- as.character.Date(paste(cpc_sel$year, cpc_sel$Month, sep = "-"))


TEST_JOIN <- left_join(us_states, cpc_sel, c=("name"="name"))


*****************************************************
STATE <- function(stat, Month = 11, data = cpc_sel) {
  my_stat <- enquo(stat)
  data %>%
    select(name, merge, plot_stat = !!my_stat) %>%
    # filter(yearID >= 1901) %>%
    group_by(name, merge) %>%
    summarize(plot_stat = sum(plot_stat)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(merge) %>%
    top_n(n_players, wt = plot_stat)
}


COVID_Plot <- function(data) {
  p <- TEST_JOIN %>%
    mutate(text_y = paste("<b>",name,
                          "</b>\n Total Variable:", 
                          signif(plot_stat,3),
                          "in 2020-2021")) %>%
    ggplot(cpc_sel) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill=plot_stat, text=text_y), color="black") +
    scale_fill_continuous("Total of Variable:", low="#EEFBE5", high="#082573") +
    my_map_theme()
  
  ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>%
    style(hoveron = "fill")
}

# Define user interface (UI) for our app
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Covid-19 Data in prisons across the United States"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("my_stat",
                  "Statistic to Plot:",
                  choices = list("Total Staff Cases" = "tota_staff_cases",
                                 "Total Prisoner Cases" = "tota_prisoner_cases"
                                 ),
                  selected = "tota_prisoner_cases"),
      sliderInput("n",
                  "Months:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 15,
                  value = 11)),
    
    # Show our plot
    mainPanel(
      h3(textOutput("TitleText")),
      h5(textOutput("SubtitleText")),
      h5("Graphs for U.S. prison covid data not implemented yet."),
      plotlyOutput("statPlot"),
      h5("Data source:", 
         tags$a(href="https://github.com/themarshallproject/COVID_prison_data/blob/master/data/covid_prison_cases.csv/", 
                "The Marshall Project Covid Prison Data")),
      h5("Graphs inspired by plots in The Marshall Project article, ", 
         tags$a(href="https://www.themarshallproject.org/2020/05/01/a-state-by-state-look-at-coronavirus-in-prisons/", 
                "\"A State-By-State Look at 15 Months of Coronavirus in Prisons\""))
    )
  )
)
  

# Define server logic required to create the graph
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$TitleText <- renderText(paste(input$my_stat, "Records over time"))
  
  output$SubtitleText <- renderText(paste("Graph shows", input$n, 
                                          "for each state across the U.S."))
  
  output$statPlot <- renderPlotly({
    COVID_Plot(STATE(stat = input$my_stat, Month = input$n, 
                             data = cpc_sel))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! To help us to help would you mind sharing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data. Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). To share your data, you could type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` for the first twenty rows of data.

Comment: ... this said: It should probably be `TEST_JOIN <- left_join(us_states, cpc_sel, by=c("name"="name"))`or simply `left_join(us_states, cpc_sel, by="name")`. This error is hard to identify from the error message and one reason why people on SO insist on a MRE.